# How to retrieve bean from Struts Tiles and use in a JSP

Tags: jsp, struts, tiles

We are using Struts Tiles 1.x in a legacy web application. In `a.jsp`, we do:

`<tiles:put name="bean" beanName="change"></tiles:put>`

Later, `b.jsp` references `a.jsp`. In `b.jsp`, we currently have a scriptlet, in which we do:

`<% DomainObject domObject = (DomainObject) TilesHelper.getAttribute("bean", pageContext); %>`

This is what `getAttribute(String,PageContext)` looks like:

```
public class TilesHelper {
    public static Object getAttribute(String name, PageContext pageContext) throws JspException {
        ComponentContext compContext = (ComponentContext) pageContext.getAttribute(
                ComponentConstants.COMPONENT_CONTEXT, PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE);

        if (compContext == null) {
            throw new JspException("Error - tag.getAttribute : component context is not defined. Check tag syntax");
        }

        return compContext.getAttribute(name);
    }
```

This works, but I don't like scriptlets. Scriptlets are ugly. I don't want any scriptlets in this JSP. I want to use a tag to access the object passed in request scope using. I've tried

`<bean:define id="domObject" name="bean" scope="request"/>`

This fails with error can't find bean bean in scope request.

How do I access the object passed in the `<tiles:put>` call in a tag like `<bean:define>` or `<jsp:useBean>`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps anyone later:
after much eye-straining forum browsing and rereads of the [documentation](https://tiles.apache.org/2.2/framework/tiles-jsp/tlddoc/tiles/useAttribute.html), I was able to decipher that the correct tag to use is

`<tiles:useAttribute id="beanId" name="beanNameHere" classname="theBeanClass" scope="request"/>`.

This declares a Java variable in scope request which can then be accessed like any other bean, in my case using EL, for example:

```
<c:if test="${beanId.class.simpleName == 'someInterestingClass'}">
    <c:out value="${beanId.someInterestingProperty}"/> 
</c:if>
```